# Databinding my Tree datastructure

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tree, .net-2.0

A set of objects is contained in a custom Tree data structure (i.e. they are Nodes).

> Each Node may have one or no Parent (root Node).
>
> Each Node may have none or many Children.

I have a datagridview that must contain all parent nodes (i.e. every node with at least one child node). The tree structure is constantly being edited (nodes added/removed). How would I go about databinding this datagridview?

I could use a bindinglist<> to contain the parent nodes, which I'd set as the datagridview's datasource. So the question is how do I keep my bindinglist updated as nodes are added removed to my Tree structure.